# mailbox.item.body.getAsync call returns different body in case of browser and desktop client

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We have noticed that when we call [`mailbox.item.body.getAsync()`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.3/Body#getasynccoerciontype-options-callback) method  (HTML coercion type) on a empty appointment item for Windows desktop client, the body returned back includes some html.

A snippet of the html is given below:

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document><meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15"><meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Word 15"><link rel=File-List href="cid:filelist.xml@01D3FDCC.17368100"><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
<o:AllowPNG/>
</o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<w:WordDocument>
<w:TrackMoves/>
<w:TrackFormatting/>
<w:EnvelopeVis/>
<w:PunctuationKerning/>
<w:ValidateAgainstSchemas/>
<w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>false</w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>
<w:IgnoreMixedContent>false</w:IgnoreMixedContent>
<w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>false</w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>
<w:DoNotPromoteQF/>
<w:LidThemeOther>EN-US</w:LidThemeOther>
<w:LidThemeAsian>X-NONE</w:LidThemeAsian>
<w:LidThemeComplexScript>X-NONE
```

The same call when performed in the web Outlook client (Chrome - Office 365) returns the body of the mail which is empty as expected.

Why is the html returned in case of Windows Desktop client ?

Comment: Perhaps it just returns different data based on the user-agent. Maybe the desktop client needs this extra info for something

Comment: The answer right inside the resource you have pointed to: "The client may modify the value passed to setAsync in order to make it render efficiently with its rendering engine.", well assume that your value is empty body. @James_Parsons answered correctly on your question.

Comment: James_Parsons response is accurate. Different clients use different engines to render the body.